# How to use saveMany in cakephp 3.2.7

Tags: cakephp-2.7, cakephp

Having problems with saveMany() on a cake 3.2.7 install. It give an error `Unknown method "saveMany"`.

```
$cartArrSave =     Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [deal_id] => 4
                [store_id] => 126
                [user_id] => 124
                [quantity] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [deal_id] => 9
                [store_id] => 127
                [user_id] => 124
                [quantity] => 1
            )

    )
    $this->Deals = TableRegistry::get('Deals');


    if(!empty($cartArrSave)){
        $this->Deals->newEntities($cartArrSave);  
        $this->Deals->saveMany($cartArrSave);  
    }
```

I have checked that saveMany is supported in even [cakephp 2](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)

And also its supported in [cakephp 3.x](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html)

Then why its giving such error?
Please suggest any alternative to saveMany function in cakephp 2.7.8?

Comment: Have you defined Deals variable in your class?

Comment: Look at what the info box under the linked section says: "_New in version 3.2.8_".

Comment: @ndm you pointed to right direction, but how its possible that 'saveMany' function supported in cakephp-2x and above 3.2.8 but not supported in 3.2.7. 

Any way any alternative to saveMany ?

Comment: Because the ORM was completely written from scratch for 3.x, and saving many entities at once simply hasn't been implemented earlier. You can simply save your entities in a loop (**https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records**), but if I were you I'd rather upgrade the CakePHP dependeny.

Comment: @ndm thanks for your clarification :) . I will try upgrading cakePHP dependency.